# Problems with parsing JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I pass this variable `strJSON` to the client page.
This variable contains this data:

```
[{"firstName":"Michael","lastName":null,"emails":["John@gmail.com"]},
 {"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"emails":["Michael@gmail.ru"]},
 {"firstName":"Olga","lastName":null,"emails":["mailOlga@gmail.com"]}]
```

I try to parse Json to JavaScript object:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(strJSON);
```

But in the row above I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data
```

I think that I get error because the JSON have to be in single quotes, so before I parse the JSON I do this:

```
strJSON= "'" + str + "'";
```

But after I added the row above, I in this row :

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(strJSON);
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Any idea what I do wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "JSON have to be in single quotes" – That's nonsense. You can use single quotes to create a JavaScript *string literal* without having to escape all the `"` but the data shouldn't include them at the ends.

Comment: [Your code does not show that error](http://jsbin.com/vajogiqifu/1/edit). Whatever your problem is, it must lie elsewhere.

Comment: to what do strJSON equals? could you add it to the post? (the above string already looks like a JSON)

Comment: The strJSON contains the string abouve I use asp.net mvc4  ViewBag feature to pass the data from server.But it dosent metter because all work done on client side with help of JavaScript.

Comment: If you do an alert(strJSON) or console.warn(strJSON) before you try JSON.parse will you get the string or an [object]? As others have suggested, maybe strJSON is not what you expect - because the JSON you pasted into your post is valid.

Comment: Just remember that the string has to be in one line, if you split it into lines as in example above it wont' work. Also `strJSON` is not a String, it's an Array.

Comment: @becquerel,when I alert(strJSON) i get alert window with this string: [{"firstName":"Michael","lastName":null,"emails":["John@gmail.com"]},
 {"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"emails":["Michael@gmail.ru"]},
 {"firstName":"Olga","lastName":null,"emails":["mailOlga@gmail.com"]}]

Answer (score 0):

first stringify the json then parse :

```
var str=[{"firstName":"Michael","lastName":null,"emails":["John@gmail.com"]},
 {"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"emails":["Michael@gmail.ru"]},
 {"firstName":"Olga","lastName":null,"emails":["mailOlga@gmail.com"]}];

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));

console.log(parsedJSON);
```

Comment: That is one of the things that I tryed:
strJSON= "'" + str + "'";

I get this error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. You tried to add quotes to an Array, not to a String.